# Failed to lock directory when installing R package using devtools::install_github()

Tags: r, devtools

When installing an R package from GitHub using `devtools::install_github()`, the following error was returned:

```
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/00LOCK-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f783’
```

When I navigate using Terminal on Macintosh `OS 10.12` to that location, it is not available ( R.framework did not appear in the "Frameworks" directory).

How can I try removing `‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/00LOCK-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f783’`? Or, is there another workaround for this?

Comment: Running `dir.exists("/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/00LOCK-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f783")` returns `FALSE`?

Comment: Hmm, doing so returned this: `Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:~ joshuarosenberg$ dir.exists("/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Res‌​ources/library/00LOC‌​K-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f‌​783")-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Res‌​ources/library/00LOC‌​K-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f‌​78`

Comment: Sorry I meant try running that command from the R console.

Comment: :) sorry about that. should have recognized the syntax. That returned: `[1] FALSE`

Comment: And running `rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Res‌​ources/library/00LOC‌​K-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f‌​783` from Terminal does not work?

Comment: that did the trick. I think I could have also, in R Studio, navigated to it in the package list and delete it there.

Answer (score 7):

Try removing `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/00LOCK-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f783`

Remove using `rm` command from your `command line`:

```
:$ rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/00LOCK-jrosen48-prcr-4f6f783
```

Then install the package again.