# Package installation problem leading error: failed to lock directory

Tags: r

Since I dont have much experience in dealing with error messages in R, can somebody help me understand what should I do after getting the following warning:

> ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/ibraim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’ for modifying
>   Try removing ‘/home/ibraim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/00LOCK-RcppEigen’
>      Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status The downloaded source packages are in ‘/tmp/Rtmp1Nll9U/downloaded_packages’

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to lock directory when installing R package using devtools::install\_github()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143608/failed-to-lock-directory-when-installing-r-package-using-devtoolsinstall-githu). The answer there should fix your problem whether you're using `devtools::install_github()` (as there) or plain `install.packages()` (at least, that's what's always fixed it for me if I got that error...)

Comment: Isn't it a common "lock" issue? That is usually resoved in linux by deleting the lock-file.

Comment: It solved the issue completely. Many thanks.